# Как сделать из файла .rc  файл .res?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать из файла .rc  файл .res?

Comment: вопрос из разряда "поищите в гугле за меня"
по первой ссылке на запрос "скомпилировать файл ресурсов rc" правильный ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
brcc32 file.rc
```